# Does summary.aov() of MANOVA object adjust for multiple comparisons?

Tags: anova, post-hoc, manova

I performed a MANOVA analysis in R, testing if two populations differ based on their multivariate phenotype, comprising 16 measurements. I then used the summary.aov() function on the MANOVA model to further assess which measurements differ between the two populations. My question now is, can this ANOVA decomposition serve as a *post hoc* test and does the summary.aov() function account for multiple testing or should I perform a false discovery rate correction?

To illustrate what I mean, here an example adopted from the R help files:

```
tear <- c(6.5, 6.2, 5.8, 6.5, 6.5, 6.9, 7.2, 6.9, 6.1, 6.3, 6.7, 6.6, 7.2, 7.1, 6.8, 7.1, 7.0, 7.2, 7.5, 7.6)
gloss <- c(9.5, 9.9, 9.6, 9.6, 9.2, 9.1, 10.0, 9.9, 9.5, 9.4, 9.1, 9.3, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 9.2, 8.8, 9.7, 10.1, 9.2)
opacity <- c(4.4, 6.4, 3.0, 4.1, 0.8, 5.7, 2.0, 3.9, 1.9, 5.7, 2.8, 4.1, 3.8,1.6, 3.4, 8.4, 5.2, 6.9, 2.7, 1.9)
Y <- cbind(tear, gloss, opacity)
rate <- factor(gl(2,10), labels = c("Low", "High"))
fit <- manova(Y ~ rate)
```

This will result in

```
summary(fit)
          Df  Pillai approx F num Df den Df   Pr(>F)   
rate       1 0.58638    7.561      3     16 0.002273 **
Residuals 18                                           
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

With the ANOVA decomposition being

```
summary.aov(fit)
Response tear :
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
rate         1 1.7405 1.74050  12.408 0.002432 **
Residuals   18 2.5250 0.14028                    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

 Response gloss :
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
rate         1 1.3005 1.30050  6.1847 0.02292 *
Residuals   18 3.7850 0.21028                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

 Response opacity :
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
rate         1  0.421  0.4205  0.1026 0.7524
Residuals   18 73.785  4.0992
```

Comment: Can't you check it by running e.g. `anova(tear ~ rate)` and then checking `summary.aov` of the outcome? If you get the same p-values, then no adjustments are done via the manova route...

Comment: Fair point, the ANOVA indeed gives the same p values. Do you have any idea if there is a direct way to extract the posthoc contrasts from the MANOVA?

Comment: I am not aware of any other way apart from some sort of manual adjustment for multiple comparisons.

Answer (score 5):

In any situation where you already have a set of unadjusted P values, you can use `p.adjust` to obtain adjusted ones for any of the methods in `p.adjust.methods`:

```
> p.adjust(c(.002432, .02292, .7524), "fdr")
[1] 0.007296 0.034380 0.752400
```

I had a much more elaborate answer using the **lsmeans** package, but it does not seem necessary. Let me know if you want to see it.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using `p.adjust` but using the Benjamini-Yekutieli method as the Type I error can be rather high with FDR (see Narum 2006 Conservation Genetics [link](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10592-005-9056-y)

Comment: Yup, that's a good idea, and the link is helpful for future passers by